# How to Integrate masterpass in app?

Tags: ios, swift, mastercard

In my app there is master pass payment method. So have to integrate MasterPass sdk in iOS application but i didn't find any sdk and any methods and there is no proper documentation in **master Pass Developer Web site**. I have only found [This](https://developer.mastercard.com/media/00/f3/a78443ef43789da36a1aadfb3cc6MTIG_Manual_US.pdf) and which is not properly given. Has anyone integrated MasterPass SDK in iOS app? [Closed]

I found the solution for this problem. If anyone needs any helps then following links can helps [MasterPass SDK](https://developer.mastercard.com/page/masterpass-merchant-sdk-for-ios)

Comment: I have been working on the integration of Masterpass Merchant for both iOS and Android. In the case of iOS I had to follow additional steps since the [documentation](https://developer.mastercard.com/page/masterpass-merchant-sdk-for-ios) offered by Masterpass is not clear enough, so I had to do some research to be able to correctly operate the little documentation offered by Masterpass. In the link I provide is an example made by me, which shows the operation of this SDK including the bridge file to link **Swift** with **Objective-C** since the Masterpass framework is written in **Objective-C**

Comment: This is the iOS SDK Document [link](https://developer.mastercard.com/page/masterpass-merchant-sdk-for-ios)

Answer (score 1):

There is not any sdk -sample available from master pass which you can use directly in your ios app. for ios , only sdk available is for QR scanning.
However, there is instruction given on their website for integrating it in ios app using native safari view controller.  here is [link](https://developer.mastercard.com/documentation/masterpass-merchant-integration#masterpass-i-os-app-to-web-implementation)

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to get `checkoutId` and other details:

- If you are a merchant then on board on masterpass.
- If you are doing integration for any merchant then ask merchant to
  send you  developer invitation. You will get consumer key and
  certificate from mastercard developer zone and use with merchant
  checkoutId.

Comment: What does `If you are a merchant then on board on masterpass` mean?